# How can I grab part of MediaWiki page title?

Tags: search, mediawiki, string-parsing

In MediaWiki 1.26.2, how can I grab part of a page title to use it in a #ifexist statement?

I need to link to different but related articles in MediaWiki, alerting the user if a page exists or do not. For that I did the following:

I have a page named `ARTICLE_NAME`. Associated with it is a page named `Notes:ARTICLE_NAME`. "Notes:" is not a namespace, but a string as `ARTICLE_NAME` is. I cannot create a namespace for Notes due to policy restrictions.

In ARTICLE_NAME page, the following code goes to check if the notes exists:

```
{{#ifexist: Notes:{{PAGENAME}} | {{alert_box}} | }
```

So if `ARTICLE_NAME` has a related `Notes:ARTICLE_NAME` page a I get a nice custom alert box highlighting the fact and linking to it.

My problem begins when I try the inverse. In the `Notes:ARTICLE_NAME` page, I need the notes to display an alert box if there is a page named `ARTICLE_NAME`. The code

```
{{#ifexist: {{PAGENAME}} | {{alert_box}} | }
```

Does nothing because `{{PAGENAME}}` brings `Notes:ARTICLE_NAME` as expected.

How can I get whatever comes after the "Notes:", using that instead of `{{PAGENAME}}` to check it with the `#ifexist` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after mucking around I found a way: remove the `Notes:` from the pagename then put it against the `#ifexist`.

```
{{#replace: {{PAGENAME}}|Notes:|}}
```

This way it replaces the `Notes:` with nothing. I made that a magic word named `ARTICLE_TITLE`, so the code that goes to notes is this:

```
{{#ifexist: :{{ARTICLE_TITLE}} | {{Alert_box}} | }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by combining `#pos` with `#ifeq`.

Example:

```
{{#ifeq:{{#pos:text1|text2}}| |text1 does not contain text2|text1 contains text2}}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I've spent some time with your code trying it but could not find a way to make it work. However, I ended with an alternative solution by using replace and removing the Notes: bit from pagename. Thanks anyway!